# Any particular way to strip away multiple words from particular text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'll give a bit of the snippit of code I made. Here it is:

```
url = urlopen("http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/scoreboard?d=2013-01-19")
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

def yahooscores():
    for table in soup.find_all('table', class_='player-title'):
        for row in table.find_all('tr'):
            date = None
            for cell in row.find_all('td', class_='yspsctnhdln'):
                for text in cell:
                    date = cell.text
            if date is not None:
                print ('%s' % (date) + ", 2013:")
```

I was trying to go about stripping the words "Scores & Schedules" from the date part of the website, but I could not somehow do it with the .split() and .strip() methods.

So, let me explain what I wish to do, with the above website as an example.

So far, this is what comes out for a date:

```
Scores & Schedule: Jan 19, 2013:
```

I just want this:

```
Jan 19, 2013:
```

Is there anything in particular I need to know in order to strip those 3 words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual content of `cell.text` is:

```
'\nScores & Schedule: Jan 19\n'
```

... so it makes more sense to get what you need out of that (the last two words) first, and *then* add `', 2013:'` to it, as I think you're trying to do already. A handy feature of `split()` is that it automatically strips leading and trailing whitespace, so probably the most robust way to get what you want is to change your last line to:

```
                print(' '.join(date.split()[-2:]) + ', 2013:')
```

This splits `date` into a list of words with `.split()`, then uses `[-2:]` to get the last two words in the list, then joins them back together with a space using `' '.join(...)`, and finally adds `', 2013:'` to the end before printing the result.

As a side note, `'%s' % (date)` in your original version does absolutely nothing: all you're doing is replacing `date` with itself. It might be worth familiarising yourself with [the documentation on percent-formatting](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) so that you understand why.

Comment: Yeah, this is the best answer. I was noticing the date had a space between the print of the ", 2013:" and this joined them together. My apologies for the % % for the date. I realized it had no purpose after I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the unwanted part with an empty string.

```
>>> "Scores & Schedule: Jan 19, 2013:".replace("Scores & Schedule:", "")
' Jan 19, 2013:'
```

Comment: Please explain why your answer works instead of just giving it. That way it'll be more useful to others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple:

```
>>> s = "Scores & Schedule: Jan 19, 2013:"
>>> s.replace("Scores & Schedule:", "")
' Jan 19, 2013:'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date = "Scores & Schedule: Jan 19, 2013:"
```

There are many options:

```
date = date[19:]

date = date.replace("Scores & Schedule: ", "")

date = date.split(":")[1].strip()+":"
```

to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

`print(date[20:].strip('\n') + ', 2013')`

this is assuming that there will ALWAYS be 'Scores & Schedule: ' in the response.